Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: decimal SSN, string FullName>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>
I got this error when I tried to make a method to return all users which have no users

CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: decimal SSN, string FullName>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I have two classes
first class
public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? FullName { get; set; }

    public string? UserName { get; set; }

    public string? Password { get; set; }

    public string? Role { get; set; }

    public decimal? EmpId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EditedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee? Emp { get; set; }

}

second class
public partial class Employee
{
    public decimal Ssn { get; set; }

    public int? EmpCode { get; set; }

    public string? EmpFirstName { get; set; }

    public string? EmpSecondName { get; set; }

    public string? EmpLastName { get; set; }

    public virtual User? User { get; set; }

}

and I want to create a method to return all users which have no users
I wrote this code in EmployeesEF class
public List<string> GetAllEmpsIsNotUser()
{
    try
    {

        var query = from emp in db.Employees
               join user in db.Users on emp.Ssn equals user.EmpId into userGroup
               from u in userGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where !db.Users.Any(u => u.EmpId == emp.Ssn)
               select new
               {
                   SSN = emp.Ssn,
                   FullName = emp.EmpFirstName + " " + emp.EmpSecondName + " " + emp.EmpLastName
               };

        return query.ToList();
    }
    catch
    {
        return new List<string>();

    }
}


Your code claims it's going to return a List<string> - but your select clause specifies an anonymous type. How do you actually expect each employee to be represented in the result? As a string, or as an object with SSN and FullName?

The compilation error is clear. You are returning the value of List<anonymous> type but your method expects to return the value of List<string> type.
Would recommend creating a DTO (Data Transfer Object) class instance.
public class UserModel
{
    public string Ssn { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

Your method should return the value of List<UserModel> type.
Also, since you are performing the LEFT JOIN query and want to obtain the record that doesn't have the User record. You can achieve it with u == null without needing the subquery to find the record from the User table (!db.Users.Any(u => u.EmpId == emp.Ssn)).
public List<UserModel> GetAllEmpsIsNotUser()
{
    try
    {

        var query = from emp in db.Employees
               join user in db.Users on emp.Ssn equals user.EmpId into userGroup
               from u in userGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where u == null
               select new UserModel
               {
                   SSN = emp.Ssn,
                   FullName = emp.EmpFirstName + " " + emp.EmpSecondName + " " + emp.EmpLastName
               };

        return query.ToList();
    }
    catch
    {
        return new List<UserModel>();
    }
}


query.ToList() returns List<anonymous> but the method's return type is List<string>. You would need to update the select clause to pick a single string value.
However, it looks like the declared return type is incorrect and you actually want something with both SSN and FullName.
You won't be able to return a list based on the anonymous type that you're selecting and need to create an class/record to contain these values.
public List<Details> GetAllEmpsIsNotUser()
{
    try
    {

        var query = from emp in db.Employees
               join user in db.Users on emp.Ssn equals user.EmpId into userGroup
               from u in userGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where !db.Users.Any(u => u.EmpId == emp.Ssn)
               select new Details(
                   SSN: emp.Ssn,
                   FullName: emp.EmpFirstName + " " + emp.EmpSecondName + " " + emp.EmpLastName
               );

        return query.ToList();
    }
    catch
    {
        return [];

    }
}

public record Details(string SSN, string FullName);

